# Call interception - How to determine wether a call is a system call

Tags: orleans

I am trying to create an interception method that only processes non-system calls. According to [the docs](https://dotnet.github.io/orleans/Documentation/Advanced-Concepts/Interceptors.html#outgoing-call-filters) both system and non-system calls are intercepted:

> Outgoing grain call filters are invoked for all method calls to a grain and this includes calls to system methods made by Orleans.

However, I cannot find a way to make the distinction using any public method or property. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of two interpretations of what a system call could be here:

1. Any call to an `ISystemTarget`
2. Any call to an interface defined in one of the Orleans assemblies

In the case of either, the simplest way to determine if a call fits that criteria is to use the `InterfaceMethod` property of the context which is passed to the call filter to check the `DeclaringType` of that `MethodInfo`.

For example:

```cs
siloBuilder.AddOutgoingGrainCallFilter(async context =>
{
    var declaringType = context.InterfaceMethod?.DeclaringType;

    // Check if the type being called belongs to one of the Orleans assemblies
    // systemAssemblies here is a HashSet<Assembly> containing the Orleans assemblies
    var isSystemAssembly = declaringType != null
      && systemAssemblies.Contains(declaringType.Assembly);

    // Check if the type is an ISystemTarget
    var systemTarget = declaringType != null
      && typeof(ISystemTarget).IsAssignableFrom(declaringType);

    if (isSystemAssembly || systemTarget)
    {
        // This is a system call, so just continue invocation without any further action
        await context.Invoke();
    }
    else
    {
        // This is an application call

        // ... Inspect/modify the arguments here ...

        await context.Invoke();

        // ... inspect/modify return value here ...
    }
})
```